# Asp.net: Repeater with Jquery slider issue

Tags: jquery, html, css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on asp.net project with asp:Repeater to display the data from database and JQuery for transitions like below:

`

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" OnItemCommand="repUsers_ItemCommand">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <div class=" col-md-3 col-sm-4">
                                <div class="thumbnail">
                                    <asp:Image ID="Image1" ImageUrl='<%#Eval("Imgpath") %>' hieght="100" Width="300" runat="server" />
                            <div class="caption">
                                 <h3>Product Name</h3>
                            <div class="slideDown">
                                 <h5>Student Name:</h5>
                                 <h5>Description</h5>
                                 <h5>Contact:</h5>
                            </div>
                                    <p>
                                        <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("Imgid")%>' CommandName="select" 
                                            Text="Select" class="btn btn-primary grabPromo" runat="server"></asp:LinkButton></a> 
                                        <a  class="btn btn-danger grabPromo" role="button">See Details</a>
                                    </p>
                            </div>
                       </div>
                 </div>
          </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:Repeater>
```

`

Jquery for slide

`

```
 $('.grabPromo').click(function (e) {
                $('.slideDown').slideToggle();
            });
```

`

Now the problem is if the "see details" button  for one div is clicked, it will slide down for all the contents in repeaters. I want to slide it for only one div one repeater content at a time. is that possible to do? if so please guide me through.
[all the details are shown on click of one repeater content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8NAsr.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change this line:

```
$('.slideDown').slideToggle();
```

to:

```
$(this).closest('div.caption').find('.slideDown').slideToggle();
```

Description: get the closest ***div.caption*** element and then find the corresponding slideDown child.

Instead, ***$('.slideDown')*** finds each element with that class.

> [jQuery.closest()](https://api.jquery.com/closest/):
>
> For each element in the set, get the first element that matches the selector by testing the element itself and traversing up through its ancestors in the DOM tree.